# Profile DLL with Dottrace

Tags: performance, dll, profiling

I am looking to run a performance profiling tool on a DLL. Ideally, Jetbrains Dottrace has this feature but I can use other programs if necessary. The application I am running is written in C# with Visual Studio 17 and the DLL is written in c++. I have access to the source code for both sides of the application. I need to remotely run an application and profile the Application along with the DLLs it calls. Previously I have been able to profile the application but cannot see the call times for any DLLs called. Is there a way to accomplish this while profiling remotely?

edit: I have tried attaching to a running process on a remote machine and the application runs, however, when I choose to profile a standalone application I have an option to profile child processes but it causes issues with running the application. I have tried running the profiler in timeline mode but I get an error saying `administrative rights are require for timeline profiling`.

Comment: Do you have the debugging symbols for these files?  As currently written your question is way too broad.  What is and isn't possible depends on the language used to compile the DLL files.

Comment: That is a good point. I will amend the post